# SQL: create new column and append values from existing table to new created column

Tags: sql, mysql, databricks

```
CREATE TABLE nearest_location(
created_date TIMESTAMP,
device VARCHAR(255),
rake_device VARCHAR(255),
is_same_location INT,
rounded_geo_lat FLOAT,
rounded_geo_lng FLOAT,
idle_or_moving VARCHAR(255),
time_diff_idle_vs_moving INT,
max_idle INT,
row_num INT
);

INSERT INTO nearest_location(created_date, device, rake_device, is_same_location, 
rounded_geo_lat, rounded_geo_lng, idle_or_moving, time_diff_idle_vs_moving, max_idle, 
row_idle)
VALUES
('2023-12-26 09:58', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.78, 69.67, 'idle', 3, 31, 1),
('2023-12-26 09:55', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.78, 69.67, 'idle', 19, 16, 
2),
('2023-12-26 09:36', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.78, 69.67, 'idle', 60, 10, 
3),
('2023-12-26 08:36', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.78, 69.67, 'idle', 60, 5, 4),
('2023-12-26 07:36', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 0, 22.78, 69.67, 'moving', 69, 2, 
5),
('2023-12-26 06:27', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.77, 69.67, 'idle', 18, 4, 6),
('2023-12-26 06:09', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 0, 22.77, 69.67, 'moving', 12, 61, 
7),
('2023-12-26 05:57', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.74, 69.67, 'idle', 17, 3, 8),
('2023-12-26 05:40', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 0, 22.74, 69.67, 'moving', 11, 60, 
9),
('2023-12-26 05:29', 'SLA16143', 'ARIL-05-SLA16143', 1, 22.74, 69.68, 'idle', 44, 1, 
10);
```

Above data contains 2 column called `max_idle` and `row_num` so whever row_num = 1 there i want to create new column and append value of rounded_geo_lat, rounded_geo_lng of max_idle=1
so new schema would look like this.
this is output i am looking for :

| created_date | device | rake_device | is_same_location | rounded_geo_lat | rounded_geo_lng | idle_or_moving | time_diff_idle_vs_moving | max_idle | rn_idle | max_idle_lat1 | max_idle_lng1 | time_diff1 | max_idle_lat2 | max_idle_lng2 | time_diff2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25-12-2023 21:22 | SLA11502 | TXDP-12-SLA11502 | 1 | 20.47 | 82.9 | idle | 23 | 10 | 1 | 21.31 | 84.1 | 61 | 21.47 | 83.97 | 62 |
| 25-12-2023 20:59 | SLA11502 | TXDP-12-SLA11502 | 1 | 20.47 | 82.9 | idle | 61 | 3 | 2 | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 25-12-2023 19:58 | SLA11502 | TXDP-12-SLA11502 | 1 | 20.47 | 82.9 | idle | 5 | 2 | 3 | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 25-12-2023 19:53 | SLA11502 | TXDP-12-SLA11502 | 1 | 20.47 | 82.9 | idle | 27 | 1 | 4 | null | null | null | null | null | null |

i tried this query but not working as expected:

```html
SELECT
    mid.created_date,
    mid.device,
    mid.rake_device,
    mid.is_same_location,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 1 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lat END) AS max_idle_lat1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 1 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lng END) AS max_idle_lng1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 1 THEN mid.time_diff_idle_vs_moving END) AS time_diff1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 2 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lat END) AS max_idle_lat2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 2 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lng END) AS max_idle_lng2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 2 THEN mid.time_diff_idle_vs_moving END) AS time_diff2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 3 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lat END) AS max_idle_lat3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 3 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lng END) AS max_idle_lng3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 3 THEN mid.time_diff_idle_vs_moving END) AS time_diff3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 4 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lat END) AS max_idle_lat4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 4 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lng END) AS max_idle_lng4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 4 THEN mid.time_diff_idle_vs_moving END) AS time_diff4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 5 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lat END) AS max_idle_lat5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 5 THEN mid.rounded_geo_lng END) AS max_idle_lng5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid.rn_idle = 1 AND mid.max_idle = 5 THEN mid.time_diff_idle_vs_moving END) AS time_diff5
FROM
    MaxIdleData mid
WHERE
    mid.rn_idle = 1
GROUP BY
    mid.created_date, mid.device, mid.rake_device, mid.is_same_location;
```

Comment: This question is of no use to any other visitors to this site..

Comment: @P.Salmon Was vandalized by OP. I've rolled it back now. If OP wishes to delete this they will have to take it up with the mods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand the problem, You want to populate the data for only in row where rn_idle = 1 and data should be taken from the max_idle = 1 row.

Try to use `WINDOW` function along with `CASE...WHEN` as follows:

```
SELECT
    mid.*,
    ROUND(case when mid.rn_idle = 1 
          then max(case when mid.max_idle = 1 then mid.rounded_geo_lat END) 
               over (partition by mid.device, mid.rake_device) END, 2) as max_idle_lat1,
    ROUND(case when mid.rn_idle = 1 
          then max(case when mid.max_idle = 1 then mid.rounded_geo_lng END) 
              over (partition by mid.device, mid.rake_device) END, 2) as max_idle_lng1
 FROM  nearest_location mid;
```

[DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CDTQAQDK)